# how to display data from productListComponentService in spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

i want to replace SearchResultsListComponent with my own to display more info than what spartacus provide OOTB when i search for something

i want to show product image, name, stock availability , price , rating

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace a component providing `ConfigModule` in your `B2cStorefrontModule`(example):

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
  cmsComponents: {
    BannerComponent: {
      component: CustomBannerComponent;
    }
  }
});
```

There is a page specifically dedicated to component customization:
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components